# div slide change to another div using css animation

Tags: jquery, html, css, animation

I have two divs (page1 + page2) inside a container (also a div)
the container has overflow:hidden property but when the animation starts the overflow configuration is ignored.
furthermore the page that supposed to be displayed when the upper page moves doesn't appear.

https://jsfiddle.net/ok0hpw3s/

```
<div class="container">
            <div class="page1 animation">11111fwefew</div>
            <div class="page2 animation">2222fewefw</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Maybe you should read [What should I do when someone answers my question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) and [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)

Answer (score 1):

To enforce the container to hide overflow, you'll need to make that absolutely positioned too.

The reason you're not seeing the page underneath is because both inner divs are given the animation class, so both are doing exactly the same thing. I'm not sure what your desired outcome is but here's an example of page2 animating to leave page1 underneath, achieved by removing the animation class off page1: https://jsfiddle.net/n40yd901/

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="page1">11111fwefew</div>
    <div class="page2 animation">2222fewefw</div>
</div>
```